# Docker 7x faster when under load

Tags: php, symfony, docker

I'm using Docker for a local dev environment on Windows. I have set up `docker-compose` to use 3 separate containers:

- PHP 7.2
- Nginx
- MariaBD

The containers host a Symfony 4 website. When I load a page, the request takes anywhere between 700-900ms to complete. However, if I run ApacheBench like this:

```
ab.exe -n 1000 -c 1 http://localhost/
```

When I now load a page (in the browser, while `ab` is running) the request times now drop to 100-200ms. The same thing happens when setting the symfony environment to `prod`. Without running ApacheBench, load times are 400-500ms, however when running ApacheBench the load times suddenly drop to just ~30ms.

Is there any way that I can get the fast response times without having to run ApacheBench constantly?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your php process manager such as ondemand. Try setting it to static and load a couple of processes.

Comment: @YvanWatchman changed the configuration from `dynamic` to `static`, but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Did you set your minimal servers higher?

Comment: It seems like a cache is used more efficiently during the load. Do you have any DB access on your page ? Try to remove them and test it.
Try to deactivate the php opcode cache too and test it

Comment: @YvanWatchman `static` uses `pm.max_children`, which was already set to `5`. Just to be sure, I changed that to `15` and tested again, but still no difference

Comment: pm.start_servers?

Comment: @FiberOptic On a request that just returns `time()` I still see the same difference. When I disable opcache, I don't see any difference but that might also be because the requests generated by `ab` are saturating my CPU anyways

Comment: @YvanWatchman the php-fpm configuration for `pm.start_servers` mentions `; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'`. I set `pm` to `static`, so that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Ah forgot... Maybe check @FiberOptic's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this is a caching issue, but not related to PHP or nginx.

Instead, it has to do with the way Docker for Windows mounts its volumes. It uses a local SMB share for this, which - as it turns out - is really slow. Instead of synchronizing changes whenever a file changes, it will check if a file has changed every time the the file is accessed.

With my limited knowledge about `cifs`, it seems like Docker configures all cifs mounts as having a 1-second cache. So when running ApacheBench, it will load a page roughly every 0.7 seconds. This keeps the `cifs` cache warm, which in turn means that manually loading a page in the browser while ApacheBench is running is fast.

My solution for this was to write a small batch script, which manually syncs the parts of the source that are likely to change every second:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob

cd /host_override
HOST_OVERRIDES="`echo *`"
for FILE in *; do
    echo "Override found for $FILE"

    cd /var/www/html
    rm -rf "$FILE"
    ln -s "/host_override/$FILE"
    cd /host_override
done

# Initial sync
cd /host_data
for FILE in *; do
    if ! [ -e "/host_override/$FILE" ]; then
        echo "Initial sync of $FILE ..."
        rsync -a "$FILE" "/var/www/html/"
    fi
done
echo "Done."

# Small sync of files that actually change
while true;
do
    for FILE in src config templates public .env; do
        rsync -aut "$FILE" "/var/www/html/"
    done

    sleep 1
done
```

I override the entry point in my `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
entrypoint: ["bash", "-c", "docker-sync & docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm"]
volumes:
    - .:/host_data:ro
    - /host_override
    - ./var:/host_override/var:rw
    - /host_override/var/log
    - /host_override/var/cache
    - ./var/user_uploads/:/host_override/var/user_uploads/:rw
    - ./docker/php/docker-sync.sh:/usr/local/bin/docker-sync
```

The 1-second delay between editing a file and the changes appearing on the host are unnoticeable, and the site is performing much better than before. Even in the `dev` environment response times are `<100ms`. In the `prod` environment, response times are `~20ms`.

Comment: Looks like something you can point out in docker's repository. Probably there's some fix already, or a configuration setup

Comment: @Frondor they seem to be aware, and don't have any improvements planned. See https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/188#issuecomment-310399973